# Accept a sentence and print only those words in reverse which has a prime number length

Tags: java, primes, stringbuilder

I am beginner in Java & I am assigned with a lot of programs for my project this week. However, this one is confusing me for a long time now. I wrote a code for it but it is **not displaying any result**. There are no syntax errors btw! Have a look- Thank You!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class primeWord_reverser
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int i,p,flag=0;

       System.out.println("Enter the sentence:");
       String SEN=sc.next();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
       SEN=SEN.toUpperCase();
       SEN=SEN+" ";

       int L=SEN.length();

       StringBuilder fnalS= new StringBuilder("");
       StringBuilder finalS=new StringBuilder("");
       for(i=0;i<L-1;i++)
       {
           char chr=SEN.charAt(i);
           if (chr!=' ')
             {
                  fnalS.insert(fnalS.length(),chr);
             }
           else if(chr==' ')
             {
                 int LfnalS=fnalS.length();
                 int m=LfnalS/2;

                 for(p=2;p<=m;p++)
                 {    
                     if(LfnalS%p==0)
                      {        
                        flag++;
                      }    
                 } 

                 if(flag==0)    
                      {
                         fnalS.reverse();
                         finalS.append(" "+fnalS); 
                      }

                  else if(flag>0)
                      {
                         finalS.append(" "+fnalS);
                      }  
                   fnalS=new StringBuilder("");
                   flag=0;
              }       
       }
       System.out.println("the sentence is: "+finalS);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it output then?

Comment: +Luud van Keulen nothing!

Comment: So not even the: `Enter the sentence:`?

Comment: nothing except that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code of:

```
String SEN = sc.next();
```

to

```
String SEN = sc.nextLine();
```

and remove `-1` on your **for loop**:

```
for(i=0;i<L-1;i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<L;i++)
```

Comment: it worked! can't believe it was such a small mistake! thanks a lot! :)

Comment: check it if my answer is right to inform others, thanks :)

Comment: yea! i wrote the comment after that! ;)

Comment: :( my bad! I am new here!

Comment: you will learn many things here in SO, Welcome to StackOverflow.